# line breaks in corrgram variable labels

Tags: r, graph

I created a correlogram, like so:

```
library(corrgram) 

corrgram(mtcars[2:6], order=TRUE, upper.panel=NULL, 
         lower.panel=panel.pie,
         text.panel=panel.txt,
         labels=rep('A very long variable name',4))
```

This produces

[image]

Is there any way to break the variable labels such that they're better readable and not partially covered by the pies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

It is as simple as putting some `'\n'` in your labels, i.e.:

```
library(corrgram) 

corrgram(mtcars[2:6], order=TRUE, upper.panel=NULL, 
         lower.panel=panel.pie,
         text.panel=panel.txt,
         labels=rep('A very long \n variable name',4))
```

[image: corrgram with line-break]

**Edit:**

In addition, you may also want to mess with the optional parameter `cex.labels`, to squeeze more text by diminishing the font size:

```
corrgram(mtcars[2:6], text.panel=panel.txt, labels=rep('...',4), cex.labels=0.5)
```